# how do i print individual items within a json object response?

Tags: jquery, get, exchange-server

i am generating a json object from data within a mySQL database. when i receive that data on the front end, i cant seem to figure out how to access individual items of that object.

here is the segment of code that is generating the object:

```
router.get('/headers', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Fetching header names');

  const queryString = 'SELECT distinct(firstName), lastName FROM testtable';

  pool.query(queryString, (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('failed query request ' + err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
      return;
    }
    const emphead = rows.map((row) => {
      return { Name: row.firstName + " " + row.lastName }
    });
    res.json(emphead);
  });
});
```

here is the segment of code that is recieving/printing the object:

```
const headers = [];
$.get({
  url: '/headers',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    headers.push(data);
  }
});
console.log(headers);
```

however when i log out the entire headers object i get

```
[]
0: Array(20)
0: {Name: "Doe John"}
1: {Name: "Woo Evan"}
2: {Name: "Diago Ivan"}
3: {Name: "Levins Victoria"}
4: {Name: "Kirkpatrick William"}
5: {Name: "Welderman Spike"}
6: {Name: "Mateo Juan"}
7: {Name: "Waldon Linus"}
8: {Name: "Jesse Tritan"}
9: {Name: "Bill Watson"}
10: {Name: "Richard Tomlin"}
11: {Name: "Foo Bar"}
12: {Name: "will mun"}
13: {Name: "jon doe"}
14: {Name: "fnam lname"}
15: {Name: "myname yourname"}
16: {Name: "ryan miller"}
17: {Name: ";alskdfj al;skdfj"}
18: {Name: "asdf adf"}
19: {Name: "paul sch"}
length: 20
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

what im trying to do is print out just {Name: "Woo Evan"} or {Name: "Jesse Tritan"}.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted, the headers variable is an array of 20 items .
You can loop on those items like and access each object's property

```
for(var i=0; i < headers.length; i++)
{
  console.log(headers[i]['Name']);
}
```

Comment: i have tried numerous ways of incrementing through the response, but every way (including the one you listed) yields me with no results at all in the console.

Comment: if i console log headers.length, i get 0.

Comment: instead of `headers.push(data);` try `headers = data;`

Comment: (index):19 []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: however, if i iterate through the data element prior to pushing the header array with what you mentioned initially, i am able to get a specific list of just the names. 
```
[]
0: "Doe John"
1: "Woo Evan"
2: "Diago Ivan"
3: "Levins Victoria"
4: "Kirkpatrick William"
5: "Welderman Spike"
6: "Mateo Juan"
7: "Waldon Linus"
8: "Jesse Tritan"
9: "Bill Watson"
10: "Richard Tomlin"
11: "Foo Bar"
12: "will mun"
13: "jon doe"
14: "fnam lname"
15: "myname yourname"
16: "ryan miller"
17: ";alskdfj al;skdfj"
18: "asdf adf"
19: "paul sch"
length: 20
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: still have no idea how to do it. so far, i have tried:

var test = headers.values(); 
console.log(test);

console.log(test.next().value);

console.log(headers.values());

console.log(headers.values);

headers.forEach(function(head){
  console.log(head);
});

for(var i=0; i < headers.values; i++){
  console.log(headers[i]);
}